# Only with certain users: UNC paths are not supported Defaulting to windows directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, unc

I have a batch file, whose purpose is to copy a directory from a network location and place it in the C: location of the user's system if it doesn't already exist. The problem is when the main user attempts this, the above message is displayed and the application subsequently errors out. BUT, when I run on my machine, to try and debug, it works just as it should with no problems.

I've seen a lot out there on this, but none where it works depending on the user. Also, most are about only working with network drives and not locals.

Here is the code. I am not the author of this .bat so let me know if something doesn't look quite right.

```
@echo off 
echo Starting Application...
rem copy files over to the users local computer to prevent .dll problems when running App
C:
CD \
if not exist "C:\App" mkdir c:\App
CD App
robocopy "\\server\shared\fuller\Apps\ThisApp" c:\App /S robocopy.log
echo You may close this window or it will close by itself when the program is done.
ThisApp1.exe
```

I've tried using popd and pushd in various spots, but I'm not sure where I would put those, or even if it's applicable to this situation.

Comment: They are running the program from a UNC path, which is why you get that error.

Comment: Why would I be able to run from the same path without error? I've ran them side by side, both from same location but on different machines.

Comment: When *exactly* does this message appear?  (You may need to remove the `@echo off` line from the batch file in order to see what it is doing.)

Answer (score 0):

Put this line as the 2nd line (right after @echo off)

```
pushd %~dp0 & REM needed in case 'Run as Administrator' or executed from network drive
```

https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html
Note that 'Run as Administrator' changes the current directory... this will put it back to where it was.